# Backspace (deleting characters) not working properly in Firefox due to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing some Javascript/Jquery for a co-worker that is supposed to edit text in a textfield as the user is typing. The purpose of the code is to add formatting to a string of characters (in particular, formatting strings of twelve characters into a valid formatted mac address), however on Firefox I am unable to use the backspace to delete characters once they have been entered into the textfield.

Here is the code that does the formatting:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var length = 0;
    $("#mac_input").focusin(function (evt) {

        $(this).keypress(function () {
            content = $(this).val();
            content_pre_format = content.replace(/\:/g, '');
            content_formatted = content_pre_format.replace(/\n/g, '');

            var text_input = $('#mac_input');

            if (content_formatted.length % 12 == 0 && length != 0) {
                text_input.val(text_input.val() + "\n");
            }

            length = content_formatted.length % 12;

            if (length % 2 == 0 && length != 0) {
                if (text_input.val().charAt(text_input.val().length - 1) == ':') {

                } else {
                    text_input.val(text_input.val() + ':');
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

**Edit:** I figured out more about the bug. When I start typing, lets say "abc", right when I type the "c" the script edits the field to show "ab:c". I can backspace the "c" and the ":" but no more. At this point the text field shows "ab", however if I use ctrl-a to select all, the text field changes to "ab:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a more robust solution (current solution will break if a user starts deleting anywhere except the end of the stirng):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#mac_input").keydown(function (event) {
    if (!((event.which > 47 && event.which < 71) || (event.which > 95 && event.which < 106))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

$("#mac_input").keyup(function () {
    var content=$(this).val();
    content = content.replace(/\:/g, '');
    content = content.replace(/\n/g, '');
    content = content.replace(/(\w{12}(?!$))/g, '$1\n').replace(/(\w{2}(?!\n)(?!$))/g, '$1:')
    $(this).val(content);
});

});
```

it ensures the string is always parsed as a collection of MAC addresses

to explain, it uses to regular expressions,
`([abcdef0123456789]{12}(?!$))` matches any sequence of twelve characters that can conform a MAC address and aren't at the end of the string (that's what the `(?!$))` lookahead does), and replaces it with the matched string and an appended newline, then it matches any sequence of 2 MAC address characters (`([abcdef0123456789]{2}`) that aren't immediately followed by a new line or the end of the string (`(?!\n)(?!$)`).

Comment: Wow, what exactly is going on in the last line? content = content.replace(/([abcdef0123456789]{12}(?!$))/g, '$1\n').replace(/([abcdef0123456789]{2}(?!\n)(?!$))/g, '$1:')

Comment: I just added a brief explanation. :)

Comment: as an addendum. this code reformats the entire string every time it changes, so that it preserves the proper MAC address format (`xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`).

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a much more concise solution than my approach!

Comment: I added character checking to allow only MAC characters. a correct answer/+1 would be appreciated! :)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote otherwise it would be all yours. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just check this: `if(event.key == "Backspace") {return;}` at the beginning of your `keypress` handler, and you should be fine.

NB: You have to add the `event` argument to your `keypress` handler function.

Comment: Wow that is awesome thank you! If you do not mind could you explain whats happening there so I can have a better understanding? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your problem came from your last if statement: before the key input was taken into account, you would add the colon, which would then be deleted after the key input was effective. That being said, if you consider Nicolás' answer to fit your problem, please prefer it to mine, as it is indeed more robust, even if it looks like voodoo magic (that's often the case when non-trivial regex come into play).